# Core Data crash with Invalid predicate: nil RHS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have this crash while executing a fetch request, but from the crash report it is clear  that the cause for the crash is that the predicate is nil. I have added a check for the case the startDate is nil. Is there any other potential cause for the invalid predicate I should take care of?

```
NSFetchRequest *calRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Calendar"];
calRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@", startDate];
calRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:calRequest error:&error];
```

Crash report

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x30534f03 __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3acc9ce7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreData                       0x30289f17 -[NSComparisonPredicate(_NSCoreDataSQLPredicateCategories) minimalFormInContext:] + 926
3  CoreData                       0x3028952b -[NSSQLGenerator initializeContextForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:nestingLevel:] + 538
4  CoreData                       0x30288f9f -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 34
5  CoreData                       0x30288e3f -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 406
6  CoreData                       0x30288aa3 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 114
7  CoreData                       0x302881e7 -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 698
8  CoreData                       0x30287c8b -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 446
9  CoreData                       0x30287539 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 2892
10 CoreData                       0x3028593b -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 614
11 MyApp                           0x0010b769 -[Calendar calendarLoad] (Calendar.m:152)
...
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `startDate` before you create your predicate? The error sounds like it's almost certainly going to be nil...

Comment: I think my problem is the way I set the startDate which sometimes causes the nil predicate. I am now logging startDate value, but the crash is very random. I just wanted to be sure there is no other possible cause.

Comment: If start date is parsed using NSDateFormatter the default settings require strict matching, which results in nil returns.  Try setting lenient true if that's the issue.

Comment: Having the same. I have few properties, always query on one object only. But only if querying one of the properties, I get this error. Martin, have you managed to solve it?